# Python : find end nodes (leaf) in gxl file

Tags: python, nodes

I have a gxl file and i want to find all of its end nodes (leaf) and store each end node name (in tag node, name attribute). 
I realized that in gxl file the end nodes are the ones which have node tag and don't have edge tag.

i want to find all the nodes which don't have any edge.

so how can i do it?
here is my gxl file sample link:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/61c1afd751214a0473fd62ee74a3b1d6

for example here node id 270 is end node because it doesnt have any edge tag. :

```
<node id="N_270"> 
<attr name="name"> 
<string>
android.content.Context 
java.lang.String getString(int) 
</string> 
</attr>
</node> 
<node id="N_271"> 
<attr name="name"> 
<string>android.view.ViewGroup 
voidinit(android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet,int) 
</string> 
</attr> 
</node>
<edge from="N_271" to="N_291" isdirected="true" id="N_271--N_291"> 
</edge>
```

Comment: Please provide a small test case in the body of your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) from the Python Standard Library.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

gxl_file_path = "C:\\some\\file\\path\\file.gxl"

tree = et.parse(gxl_file_path)
root = tree.getroot()  # At this point you can traverse the node structure as needed
```

Say you needed to find the name of a node:

```
>>> root.tag
'gxl'
```

Or if you wanted to iterate over all edge nodes:

```
for edge in root.iter('edge'):
    # ... Logic ...
```

I can't tell exactly what you're trying to parse, but i believe you should iterate over the 'node' nodes, to the extent of something like this:

```
for node in root.iter('node'):
    if node.find('attr'):  # If the attribute node is present
        name = node.find('attr').get('name')
```

Comment: thanks for answering.
how can i find the end node? for example here node id 270 is end node because it doesnt have any edge tag. :
<node id="N_270">
<attr name="name">
<string>android.content.Context java.lang.String getString(int)
</string>
</attr>
</node>
<node id="N_271">
<attr name="name">
<string>android.view.ViewGroup void init(android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet,int)
</string>
</attr>
</node>
<edge from="N_271" to="N_291" isdirected="true" id="N_271--N_291">
    </edge>

Comment: That isn't a valid excerpt from your provided .gxl file - I'm having trouble understanding how you wish to indicate the 'end'... However I have given you documentation for traversing xml files, as well as some examples, so that you might use this information and find out for yourself.

Comment: i want to find all the nodes which don't have any edge. what is the code?